# Implications and remedies of fixed 'H' in Pedersen commitment

Tags: privacy, cryptography

In the monero document "Zero to Monero" pp. 30 the Pedersen Commitment scheme is described as requiring generators `G, H` such that no-one knows an `x` where `G = x*H`. The actual `H` is defined as `H=to_point(Keccak(G))` where `to_point` is a function mapping scalars to elliptic curve points. Gregory Maxwell describes this function in more detail:

> ... Where to_point() takes the input as the x value of a new point, checks that its on the curve and solves for the y value. ...

Rather than simply multiplying by `G`, somewhat breaking the scheme.

However, if someone was to figure out the `x` above doesen't this become a single, centralized point-of-failure for the entire currency? Meaning that by breaking this single, 128-bit secure key, absolutely all monero transactions - future and past - could be decoded w.r.t. the amounts sent? As a follow up: would it be possible for the sender to pick a fresh `H` for every transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commitment is actually *xG + aH* where both *G* and *H* are pre-defined generators. The
hardness of the discrete logarithm problem ensures calculating *a* from *H* (or *x* from *G*) is infeasible. Put another way, both *G* and *H* are points, and because of ECC point multiplication, you can't deduce *x* or *a*.

Further, you'll see described in Maxwell's Confidential Transactions [paper](https://people.xiph.org/~greg/confidential_values.txt):

```
The Pedersen commitment is created by picking an additional generator
for the group (which we'll call H) such that no one knows the discrete
log for H with respect to G (or vice versa), meaning no one knows an
x such that xG = H. We can accomplish this by using the cryptographic
hash of G to pick H:

    H = to_point(SHA256(ENCODE(G)))
```

Which is precisely how *H* is constructed in Monero: *H = Hp(G)*, which is `H = to_point(Keccak(G))`.

Further:

> However, if someone was to figure out the x above doesen't this become a single, centralized point-of-failure for the entire currency?

No. *x* is a binding factor in a single commitment. A centralized point of failure would be if someone knew the discrete log for *H* with respect to *G* (or vice versa). If one miraculously calculated an *x* in one commitment, this wouldn't compromise other commitments. Think about it like this: just because you know your *x* for a commitment, doesn't mean you can work out other *x*'s.

Also:

> As a follow up: would it be possible for the sender to pick a fresh H for every transaction?

That's essentially what happens because of the point multiplication using *a*. E.g. *aH*.

Comment: "A centralized point of failure would be if someone knew the discrete log for H with respect to G (or vice versa)." This is what I'm asking, as basically all transactions use the same G and H. But is there any technical reason for keeping H constant?

Comment: The fact that G and H are known is irrelevant. What matters is you don't know an x such that xG = H.

Comment: What matters is that somebody else might know the x, without me knowing this fact.

Comment: Then they would know how to defeat the discrete log problem and everything that relies on ECC would be broken.

Comment: It's more a question of resources, surely breaking one key for the whole network, costing e.g. $ 1B, is cheaper than breaking one key per transaction. It's also a question of time, as 80-bit encryption is no-longer considered secure (although it still costs something to break each key) and ECRYPT standards (https://www.keylength.com/en/3/) indicate that the curve is only secure for at least 10 years. Besides, if/when this break occurs the key could be replicated and shared with select blockchain analysis companies creating cheap, asymmetric transparency to the blockchain.

Comment: We are dealing with 256-bit keys here for ECC, not 80-bit keys for Symetric. This is not the place to get into a debate on how long 256-bit ECC will be secure for however.